# Prove that, given two distinct subspaces of R^N, W and U, of dimension N-1, the subspace (U ∩ W ) has dimension N-2.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Intuitively, it's clear.. If we have two planes, they intersect in a line. If we have two lines, they intersect in a point.

I'm aware that dim(U + W) = dimU + dimW − dim(U ∩ W )

So we get

dim(U+W) = 2N-2 - x

But how do I find dim(U+W)? This is what I've tried:

Consider a basis for R^N i.e (b1,b2,b3....b^n) 
W and U have dimension N-1, and are distinct, so there will be one basis vector which they do not have in common. 
Now, if W = span (b2,b3...b^n) and U = span (b1,b2,b3,...b^n-1) 
Then it is clear that W+U = span(U) + span (W) = span (b1,b2,b3...b^n ) = R^N

But the problem is that it may not be possible to write W as the span of the given basis vectors. To illustrate my point, a basis for a vector space has 2 properties : 
1)All the vectors are linearly independent
2)All the vectors in the basis belong to the vector space

If we consider the line y=x, and the basis for R^2 ( (0,1) and (1,0) ) , we can clearly see that the line y=x cannot be made from the span of only (0,1) or (1,0). And so, I am stuck.

Comment: The point is that $U+W=\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the maximality of the dimensions of the two *proper* spaces $\;U,\,W\;$ , we have that

$$U,\,W\le U+W\le\Bbb R^n\implies U,\,W=U+W\;\;\text{or}\;\;U+W=\Bbb R^n$$

as there is no possibility for a dimension strictly between $\;n-1\;$ and $\;n\;$ .

But $\;U=U+W\;$ is impossible , since then $\;W\le U\implies W=U\;$ (why?), contradicting the fact these two are *different* subspaces, and likewise for $\;W=U+W\;$.

Thus, it must be $\;U+W=\Bbb R^n\;$ .

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. What if we had two subspaces U and W of dimension N-1 and N-2?